# Turning userInput --> "userInput.txt"

Tags: c++

i'm trying to make a simple text editor in c++ and I've come across a problem!
When the user is making their new file I am not sure how to take their input and make it a .txt file.

The problematic code is

```
ofstream newFile(userInput);
```

It now makes a file called "userInput" but I does not make a .txt file, any tips on how I would solve this?

Here is the whole code in case it helps or if you have any tips!
:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string userInput;
int amoutFiles = 1;
string files[100];

void read();
void write();
void create();
void listAll();
void storage();
void open();

int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to zer0's text editor" << endl;
    cout << "Do you wish to :" << endl;
    cout << "1: Create file" << endl;
    cout << "2: Read Existing file" << endl; // Google getLine();
    cout << "3: Write to file" << endl;
    cout << "4: List all files" << endl;
    cin >> userInput;

if (userInput == "1")
{
    create();
    cin >> userInput;
}
else if (userInput == "2")
{
    open();
    read();
    cin >> userInput;
}
else if (userInput == "3")
{
    open();
    write();
    cin >> userInput;
}
else if (userInput == "4")
{
    listAll();
    cin >> userInput;
}
return 0;
}

void read() //Displays text inside .txt file
{

}
void write() //Prints text to exsisting file
{
    ofstream myFile;
    open();
    cout << "Enter the text you want to add:" << endl;
    cin >> userInput;
    myFile << userInput << endl;
    myFile.close();
}
void create() //Creates a new file 
{
    cout << "Please pick a name for the file" << endl;
    cin >> userInput;
    ofstream newFile(userInput);
    files[amoutFiles] = userInput;
    storage();
    amoutFiles++;
}
void listAll() //Lists all files as a part of an array
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < amoutFiles; i++)
    {
        cout << files[i] << endl;
    }
}
void storage()
{
    ofstream fileList;
    fileList.open("fileList.txt");
    fileList << userInput << endl;
}
void open()
{
    ofstream myFile;
    cout << "What file do you wish to open? : " << endl;
    cin >> userInput;
    myFile.open(userInput);
}
```

Comment: OBS! It isn't that pretty but I've just started :) A lot of things I have to fix up and make it look more tidy!

Comment: In `open()`, `ofstream myFile;` is a local variable and only exists inside the function. When the function ends, the `ofstream` destructor is called which closes the file.

Comment: When you type in the value that gets stored in user input do you type in "aName" or "aName.txt"?

Comment: @Maria I just write "test" and not "test.txt" and I see how that would be a solution, but i'm still wondering if there isn't a coding way around having the user type ".txt"

Comment: @Alexanderrost Did you try appending the `".txt"` to the string?

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyMopp ill be sure to fix that! I'm still new to c++ so i'm just full trail n error mode, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the user to just type the name and not the file type, you should append `".txt"` when creating the file.

```
ofstream newFile(userInput + ".txt");
```

The only issue with this is that if a user does enter the full filename with extension you'll end up with a file named `"myGreatName.txt.txt"`.

If you are interested in fixing that you should look up C++ string manipulation functions (start [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string)) and try to see how you could find out whether the string ends in `".txt"` or not.